# How to use same model or json for different rest end points

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, api, rest

I am developing spring boot app for multiple REST API. Here, Request and Response JSON structure (header, from, dest, time, body, version, signature) are same except body elements.

Body elements fields are different. In other requests, body elements has different fields and other elements are same.

For this am duplicate the class for each request and response. Is there any good solution available? Appreciate your support.

Ex

```
1. 
{
Message:{},
Payload:{
Header:{},
Body:{ data:", name:"}},
Version:{}
}

2. 
{
Message:{},
Payload:{
Header:{},
Body:{ code:", desc:"}},
Version:{}
}

3. 
{
Message:{},
Payload:{
Header:{},
Body:{ format:", count:"}},
Version:{}
}
```

Comment: why not use has a relationship if you can modify your json like 
```{
   "common" : {
      //elements
    },
   // exclusive element
}```
or else if you don't want to change the json use inheritance and pull out the common fields in a parent class

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Here, I couldn't modify the JSON. Could give some json references for inheritance. Simple Single step json fine but here required 3 traversal to reach extract block. So, how to keep placeholder.